# How to add MySQL services into Consul Docker container?

Tags: mysql, docker, consul

I am using Windows 10 and Docker Desktop. I pull Consul Docker images from Docker repository and try to containerize Consul Docker server to discover MySQL services. To add MySQL service into Consul Docker, I type in CONSUL environment variables.

For example:

```
CONSUL_SERVICE_ID=mysql
CONSUL_SERVICE_NAME=mysql8
CONSUL_SERVICE_ADDRESS=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
CONSUL_SERVICE_PORT=3306
```

But Consul Docker server can not discover the MySQL service when running the Consul container. The Docker images I pull are `consul` and `gliderlabs/consul-server`.

How can I register MySQL service into Consul Docker server? When installing Consul server on localhost, not containerizing, Consul server discover the MySQL service successfully. I have no idea how on Docker.

Comment: Where is your mysql server running? Is it part of the same compose file as of consul's? Is mysql even containerised at all or running independently on the machine?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. On the same host. But running on different container.

Comment: I'd suggest you put them in the same `docker-compose` file and then they'd be able to detect each other using the service name (defined in the compose file) as their DS entry. In case, it's a necessity for you to keep them separate, have you exposed the port of your mysql server? (see if you can access Mysql from your host machiner (without any containers involved).

Comment: Mysql docker container can be connected from localhost, outside the container. Are there consul environment variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define an externally running container in a docker-compose file that is not actually defined in the same file using `external_links`.

> **external_links**
>
> Link to containers started outside this docker-compose.yml or even
>   outside of Compose, especially for containers that provide shared or
>   common services. external_links follow semantics similar to the legacy
>   option links when specifying both the container name and the link
>   alias (CONTAINER:ALIAS).
>
> ```
> external_links:
>  - redis_1
>  - project_db_1:mysql
>  - project_db_1:postgresql
> ```

[Source](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file)